# Django form fields not showing

Tags: python, django, forms

I am new to django and trying to show a form in an html file and I don't see the fields when I get to this particular page on my browser.

Here is the html file : In which I can see everything but the form showing up two_factor.html

```
{% extends 'authentication/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Two Factor{% endblock title %}

{% block two_factor %}
    <div class="container">
    <h3>Your code</h3>
    <form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock two_factor %}
```

my forms.py

```
class TwoFactorForm(forms.Form):
    code = forms.CharField(label='Code', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'placeholder': 'Your code'}))
```

my views.py

```
class TwoFactorView(View):
    form_class = TwoFactorForm
    template_name = 'authentication/two_factor.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            return redirect('authentication/secret.html')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

I added block in the base.html. I am seeing only button submit. URL is all good.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious here. I know you say the URL is right but can you confirm that the get and post methods are correctly being called, eg by putting `print` statements there? Or even add another parameter to the render call and outputting that in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Change the view class to

```
class TwoFactorView(View):
 form_class = TwoFactorForm
 template_name = 'authentication/two_factor.html'

 def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

 def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        return redirect('authentication/secret.html')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Instead of using

```
form = self.form_class(None)
```

Use

```
form = self.form_class()
```

Comment: it's not that. The form is not displayed during the transition from form to form via render(). But the form is displayed when passing through the redirect().

Comment: @Kepchyk:The form is not displayed after the user enters invalid data? Invalid data means `render` is called in `post`. What do you mean with _transition_?

Answer (score -1):

In the last lines of your html code, try and replace,

```
{% endblock two_factor %}
```

with just

```
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Wrong, read the docs: "For extra readability, you can optionally give a name to your `code`{% endblock %} tag". The html code of the op is therefore valid.

Comment: My bad.. thanks for the heads up.. Won't make this again.. Appreciate you pointing out, by the way...